# complex mysql query order by time online

Tags: mysql

How I query this table:

(microtimer is float, omit by simplicity)

```
microtimer(php),user,operation
123456,albert,login
123459,juan,login
123467,maria,login
123469,juan,logout
123479,albert,logout
123480,juan,login
123498,maria,logout
123499,juan,logout
```

desired results: (Sorted by time online)

```
time online,user
(123498-123467)=31,maria
(123479-123456)=23,albert
(123499-123480)=19,juan
(123469-123459)=10,juan
```

=====================================
There are 1 problem

Pedro 45.43434343
Pedro 12.23232323
Pedro 7.4534535353
me 90.069999933242798
me 12.1212121212121

Desired global sort
Code:

```
<?php
...
$query ="
select t.usuario, (logouttimer - logintimer)
from (select t.usuario, t.relogio as logintimer, 
             (select t2.relogio
              from logdiario t2
              where t2.usuario = t.usuario and
                    t2.relogio >= t.relogio and
                    t2.canal = 'Logout'
              order by t2.relogio asc
              limit 1
             ) as logouttimer
      from logdiario t
      where t.canal = 'Login'
     ) t;
";

$q=mysql_query($query,$db);
$n=mysql_numrows($q);

for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
echo mysql_result($q,$i,"t.usuario");
echo " ".mysql_result($q,$i,"(logouttimer - logintimer)");
echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: My desire is a ranking users<br>1.Pedro 45 minutes online<br>2.Maria 41 minutes online<br>3.Pedro 39 minutes online<br>4.Juan 36 minutes online<br>5.Maria 29 minutes online<br>Yes multiple logins/logouts from same people generate various entries, i am on bad approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You want the first logout record after each login.  You can get that using a correlated subquery.  Then to take the difference:

```
select t.user, (logouttimer - logintimer)
from (select t.user, t.microtimer as logintimer, 
             (select t2.microtimer
              from thistable t2
              where t2.user = t.user and
                    t2.microtimer >= t.microtimer and
                    t2.operation = 'logout'
              order by t2.microtime asc
              limit 1
             ) as logout_timer
      from thistable t
      where t.operation = 'login'
     ) t;
```